# QTableView formatting numbers

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qsqltablemodel

I have created a delegate and i'm able to align and boldface the numbers on the table. I would like to force them to have two decimal places, for example 1.2 should show as 1.20.
This is the header of the delagete:

```
#ifndef TOTALDELEGATE_H
#define TOTALDELEGATE_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QStyledItemDelegate>


class TotalDelegate : public QStyledItemDelegate
{
public:
  TotalDelegate();

  virtual void paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const Q_DECL_OVERRIDE;
};

#endif // TOTALDELEGATE_H
```

Here is the implementation:

```
#include "totaldelegate.h"

TotalDelegate::TotalDelegate()
{

}

void TotalDelegate::paint(QPainter *painter, const QStyleOptionViewItem &option, const QModelIndex &index) const
{
  if(!index.isValid()) return;
  QFont font=option.font;
  font.setBold(true);

  QStyleOptionViewItem localOption(option);
  localOption.font=font;
  localOption.displayAlignment=Qt::AlignRight;
  QStyledItemDelegate::paint(painter,localOption,index);

}
```

Still a little lost on how to control the alignment so it forces two decimals. Also i would like to know how to change the background color.
Thanks for the help.
Here is the model:

```
  body = new QSqlTableModel(parent,data->m_db);
  body->setTable("C"+QString::number(markTime.toSecsSinceEpoch()));
  body->select();
  ui->bodyView->setModel(body);
  ui->bodyView->sortByColumn(0,Qt::AscendingOrder);
  ui->bodyView->setColumnWidth(0,30);
  ui->bodyView->setColumnWidth(1,80);
  for(int x=2;x<ui->columns->maximum()+2;x++) ui->bodyView->setColumnWidth(x,40);
  ui->bodyView->setEditTriggers(QAbstractItemView::NoEditTriggers);
  ui->bodyView->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
  ui->bodyView->setAlternatingRowColors(true);

//  //  ***************  Testing  ********************
  ui->bodyView->setItemDelegateForRow(10,new TotalDelegate);

//  //  *****************Testing  ********************

  ui->bodyView->show();
```

Comment: What is your model?

Comment: I just updated the post with the model

Comment: Do you want all numbers to have decimals, or only those that already have decimals?

Comment: @eyllanesc - yes i would like to have all numbers to show decimals.

Comment: @Scheff - all the data displayed in the QTableView is coming from the SQL model. All the columns in the database are setup as float, the "C"+QString::number(markTime.toSecsSinceEpoch()) is only used to serialize the name of the temporary working table. markTime is a DateTime object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to create a custom QSqlTableModel class and override the `QVariant QSqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const` method.

In the case of setting how it will be shown we use the `Qt::DisplayRole` role as a filter, and in case of changing the background color we will use the `Qt::BackgroundRole`:

***.h**

```
#ifndef CUSTOMSQLTABLEMODEL_H
#define CUSTOMSQLTABLEMODEL_H

#include <QSqlTableModel>

class CustomSqlTableModel : public QSqlTableModel
{
public:
    CustomSqlTableModel(QObject *parent = Q_NULLPTR, QSqlDatabase db = QSqlDatabase());

    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole) const;
};

#endif // CUSTOMSQLTABLEMODEL_H
```

*.cpp

```
#include "customsqltablemodel.h"

#include <QBrush>

CustomSqlTableModel::CustomSqlTableModel(QObject *parent, QSqlDatabase db):QSqlTableModel(parent, db)
{

}

QVariant CustomSqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole){
        if(index.column()  == 4)
            return QVariant(QString::number(QSqlTableModel::data(index, role).toDouble(), 'f', 2));
    }

    if (role == Qt::BackgroundRole){
        if(index.row()  == 4)
            return QVariant(QBrush(Qt::blue));
    }
    return QSqlTableModel::data(index, role);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The problem with this solution is that is affecting the whole table, i only want to affect one line with the background color. Other thing is how do you put a "," to separate the 1,000s? Is hard for me to believe that is not a "function" that can mask the display of numbers, like in Excel "#,##0.00" for example.

Comment: Please do not extend the question, to be precise that row you want to be painted of a certain color, what is the criterion?

Comment: Be more specific please. Because the model is different at the time of editing than the display

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I see how you doing that. Was not my intention to extend the question, which is basically how to format the numbers for display so the sheet looks professional.

Comment: My answer is general, you must accommodate the code for your specific case. I help you my answer?

Comment: Yes it did, It just seems to me that such a powerful language does not have a easy facility to make the screen look more professional.

Comment: What do you mean by more professional? Any language can do it, it all depends on the programmer. :P

Comment: I do understand that depends on the programmer. To me, and this is just my opinion, when creating the structures for the table view i would have added some functionality to easily change alignments, fonts, colors, formats, etc. Don't get my wrong I love the QT framework, is just that in few occasions fund myself skipping "beautifying' something because of the extra work that entitles.

Comment: For you how should the background color be elegantly changed, ie what function should there be?

Comment: I would envision something like this: ui->myTableView->setColumnFormat(2,"#,###.00"); ui->myTableView->setRowFormat(10,Qt::bold);

Comment: This type of functions involves storing the data in memory for each element, that is, let's say in total that data occupy b bytes, then for all the elements of the table would be used b * number_of_columns * number_of_rows, so that it would spend too much memory Unnecessarily. Qt looks for the best performance and tells the author that it will create it through a function. Also in Qt the model not only involves the data but this is only a role as there are the roles of Qt::DisplayRole, Qt::BackGroundRole, etc.